# Do I have to use external clock for ATmega ISP programming after changing fuse bits?

Tags: atmega, programming, fuse-bits

After programming an ATmega microcontroller via ISP (SPI) interface and changing the *clock-related fuse bits*, I'd like to reprogram it again. Will I have to connect it to an external clock now to do so, or will I *always* be able to program it by clocking just via SPI's SCLK line, without external clock (like in image below)?

(in the image below, the programmer is a Raspberry Pi)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hmh, found [an answer to other similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/79773/4699):

> You do *not* need any crystal circuitry in place for programming a blank off the line AVR (as they come running off the internal oscillator), but if trying to *reprogram* a chip that is fused for an external crystal, you will need a comparable crystal and load capacitors in circuit (unless you use a high voltage programming mode).

so for now I understand that the answer is I can't use the above simple circuit after changing the fuse bits, I have to extend it with a clock matching the fuse bits configuration.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Even in oscillator mode (where a crystal is expected) you can feed a plain digital clock on the XIN pin. You don't really need to find a matching crystal.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on just what you set the clock source fuse bits to. The default configuration is usually to run off an internal 8MHz oscillator divided down to 1MHz; other configurations include external clock (typically on XTAL1 pin) and various crystal modes (with a crystal resonator across XTAL1 and XTAL2). In each of these modes, clock rates down to DC are supported, so the chip will be effectively frozen if it doesn't receive a clock input. However, in oscillator mode XTAL2 is essentially an inverted amplification of the XTAL1 input just to get the resonator swinging, and you could therefore simply feed a clock into XTAL1 in all cases. It will simply be ignored if the internal oscillator is used.

The two combinations that cause trouble are:

1. If you're not currently programming the chip, and it runs from internal oscillator, it could configure the XTAL1 pin as an output. If you're also driving it externally this conflict can fry I/O buffers.
2. The clock rate in the AVR must be faster than the SPI clock. This can mean the XTAL1 input needs to be considerably faster (for instance, as much as 3*512 times in an ATmega644).

Comment: problem 1 can be solved using a series resistor etween your oscillator and the chip,  1K would probably be a good choice.